# Dell Inspiron AllInOne 2310 screen error

Tags: graphics-card, dell-inspiron

The screen of my 9 years old Computer (Dell Inspiron AllInOne 2310) is showing a lot of bad pixels since the first start screen of Dell until a Windows error is shown.

Do you think is a problem of the (integrated) video card or it's a screen problem? Is there any way to confirm that problem connecting an output screen or similiar? I haven't found any output video port. Perhaps is a Windows problem, but I think that the problem wouldn't start at first dell splash screen.

I think that it's the first one, in that case, could I install an external video card to solve it? Or I must to change the processor?

I attach some sample images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the computer is 9 years old, I'd suggest it's a simple case of 'its broken'. The solution to this problem is to buy a new computer.

However, in an attempt to be slightly more helpful:

The pixelation could be caused by a loose/damaged cable between the motherboard and screen (maybe).
Or it could be caused by a bad graphics card.
Or it could be caused by the driver being corrupted.
Or your video ram could be damaged. In this PC the ATI Radeon uses integrated memory, meaning it uses your main RAM.

The driver would likely only be corrupted if the hard disk was damaged, or if Windows encountered a bad error at some point and didn't shut down well. I've had Windows corrupt my hard disk when a fan failed and the computer overheated for example.

The error with the blue screen indicates that more than just the screen is broken. Windows is saying there is something wrong with the Windows install, and it won't boot properly. This could happen if the hard disk is damaged or corrupted. Usually if your RAM is broken you wouldn't get to this point, but it is possible a dodgy RAM stick is causing the boot and screen errors. It could be a problem with the motherboard.

Sometimes the reason that internal PC components fail is because the power supply is failing and damaged them.

So really, the question is too broad and will probably be closed for that reason. I think I've listed almost each internal component above, so troubleshooting each of those in turn will take you a while and some money.

My advice is:

1. Buy a new computer, get the hard disk out of the old one and into an external USB hard disk holder, and copy any important files to the new PC
2. If you really want to try repairing the old PC, ring the Dell support phone number and pay for a technician to come to you. They will be able to diagnose the problem better than us, and potentially arrange replacement parts.

Comment: Thanks for the extense response, I know that it's old and the first advice is the smartest, but I would know if any cheaper solution could be tried to solve the problem...